# Keyboard with macros support from Blizzard

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

I thought macros are prohibited from use in Starcraft 2 multiplayer, but recently I've found a keyboard being sold by Blizzard:

http://us.blizzard.com/store/details.xml?id=1100001142

> Designed specifically for Blizzard Entertainment's highly anticipated Starcraft® II Wings of Liberty™, SteelSeries introduces the StarCraft® II Limited Edition Zboard™ Keyset. The custom designed keyset features labeled game commands on each key, in-game shortcuts, and artwork from the game.
>   **The gaming experience will enhance drastically due to one-touch macros** and the ability to fully customize each key. This Limited Edition Keyset is a valuable tool for StarCraft II players looking to immerse themselves in the game and improve their performance and actions per minute (APM).

What does the bolded statement mean and what macros are supported/provided by this keyboard?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm especially interested in what the race buttons are supposed to do for the user. They make it seem like that they change the functionality of the numbered macro keys depending on race.

Comment: @Shaun: Yeah, I think they allow per-race setting. [A bonus if you can find the typo in the race names](http://www.gamersdailynews.com/userfiles/SteelSeries_Zboard_Limited_Edition_StarCraft_II_Keyset.jpg)...

Comment: @TomWij: Yeah, I noticed that misspelling. Quite the blunder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought macros are prohibited from use in Starcraft 2 multiplayer[...] - [Budda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17622/85)

### DATELINE TARSONIS SECTOR

[image]

Reports have been coming in of Blizzard banning players.

Pros can't be reached for comment, and Noobs are holding on for their dear lives.

We have confirmed reports that users have been banned.  The following is a quote from one user:

> So i was banned last friday for using "Third party" hardware that creates an unfair advantage
>
> i was using the g19 logitech keyboard.
>
> aparently bliz has a way to find if you macro onto keyboards.
>
> I was using it for build orders, very simple macros to pop out some units with one button instead of 2.
>
> wtf.
> Merikh (Platinum Protoss)

WTF indeed.

We now go live to Connie Chung with a response to Merikh by Blizzard... Connie?

Earlier today we met up with World of Warcraft GM Taudarak and he had this to say:

[image]

Dark news for keyboarding macro users every where.

Next up: Sports! Can the Nagrand Stranglers take on the Kapulu Roughriders?  More after these messages

Comment: This is a very poor answer to the question. The OP said as much that he "thought macros were prohibited from use", but that this new keyboard from Blizzard designed specifically for SC2 was talking about having one-touch macro keys. He's asking what those keys do. If anything, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Mana I'm not sure if you read the answer from Taudarak, but it explains his confusion.  Macros are prohibited from use: even the ones on this keyboard.  While a keyboard can be designed and marketed to Starcraft with macro's, that doesn't mean you're allowed to use them during play.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I still don't get what's with the whole tone of this answer though.

Comment: @Mana Instead of just linking the one image (which is what it would take to answer the question), I figured I'd put a humorous tone on the whole thing

Comment: @tzenes This answers the OPs confusion as to whether or not Blizzard supports macros (something I had trouble proving one way or the other myself since pretty much all I found was people complaining one way or the other about macro use in unofficial terms). However, it doesn't address what the keyboard actions do given the fact that Blizzard doesn't allow macros. That's probably why this answer is getting down-vote spam, although I think it deserves at least "no vote" (if not an upvote) since it answers part of the question (and the part that is arguably harder to verify via Google).

Comment: @Shaun the keys are macros exactly like Budda's post says.  They're illegal, just like my answer says.  There is no mystery here.  He thought that they must do something else because it was branded by Blizzard (and Blizzard doesn't allow macros), but the reality is they don't do anything special, they're just macros.  Blizzard allows you to use a keyboard which contains macros as long as you don't use them yourself (as the answer says).  I'm sorry if people don't like how I presented the answer as a joke, but its still correct and I'm not change it.

Comment: We're not talking about the Logitech G19 or World of Warcraft...

Comment: @tzenes The joke isn't the problem... I appreciated the novelty of it. If you were to edit your newscast to include the tidbit about the fact that the Zboard's keyboard macro buttons aren't approved by Blizzard for use in Starcraft *because they aren't anything other than macro buttons* (aside from group selectors or something similar), then the answer would be perfect.

Comment: @Tom Starcraft player got banned, Starcraft player emailed blizzard, blizzard GM responded.

Comment: @Shaun its CW if you really think it's necessary.  I don't think people would downvote an answer because wasn't complete while just leaving the other answers alone.  I really do think they didn't appreciate the humor.

Comment: @tzenes: Thanks for clarifying, found the relevant thread.

Comment: @tzenes Possibly. If that's the case, then fooey on them.

Comment: Guys, I'm getting more confused with each comment. Tzene, if I understood you in the correct way, you mean that keyboard DOES have keys with macros, but those macros are still not allowed for playing StarCraft. Then what is a point to buy such STARCRAFT2 keyboard that is NOT allowed to use keyboard features in game? What is a point for Blizzard to create a game keyboard that doesn't allow you to use keyboard features in game? P.S. I like humor very much, but could you please comment now without humor (just to be clear)?

Comment: @Budda: They ambiguously misused the term *macro* as a marketing word. Tzenes assumes that the keyboard does allow you to program your own macros or select ones that will allow you to be better than people without such keyboard. Please note that Blizzard *branded* this keyboard and didn't *create* it. But as Blizzard has this keyboard in their marketplace they confirm that you are allowed to use these macros, which remap keys and shortcuts but don't allow you to do any form of automation.

Comment: @Tom I think you're misrepresenting what I said and I'd appreciate it if you didn't speak for me

Comment: @Budda the Steel series provides a large number of features including: Keysetts (which change what keys are bound to which), 9 Programmable keys (which are traditionally used for issuing commands to Windows to start new programs), and 28 "One-Touch" keys, which provide `Functions that would normally require a complex combination of keys to accomplish, or would necessitate navigating through many layers of windows, can be accessed simply and easily by  enabling the Pad Area (see ‘‘Pad LED’’) or Bar Area (see ‘‘Bar LED’’) and  pressing the appropriate key.`

Comment: citation: http://cdn.steelseries.com/userguides/zboard/ZBD101_UG5.0_EN.pdf  By default these do not come programmed with macros for Starcraft (or any other Blizzard game) and default to Internet Explorer and Windows Specific Functions.   However, you can reprogram these (and 9 of the 10 Programmable Keys) to produce multiple key strokes for Blizzard games (thus violating ToS).  This would require you to custom edit the software supporting the keyboard (as many players do).

Comment: @tzenes: I don't think so, you confirmed. +1 for clicking throught to the manual!

Comment: @Tom it also helps that I used one at Blizzcon and the guys there specifically said that you shouldn't use the macro's to emulate multiple key presses or you'd get banned

Answer (score 2):

**One key should be for one single action**.
If not, you fool yourself and you are considered cheating…

The one-touch macros are on the right:

> It can be fully customized through the use of the included SteelSeries Z Engine software, which enables macros to be dragged and dropped onto specific keys by use of the program.

For more information, refer to [the SteelSeries Zboard website](http://steelseries.com/products/games/starcraft-ii/steelseries-zboard-limited-edition-starcraft-ii) and [a screenshot for the Zboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V57JO.jpg).

An example of the Z Engine which supports a lot of different games and Z keyboards:

[image]

Comment: But what is the functionality of those macro keys? Those "MACRO" keys for Protoss, Terran, Zerg - what they do?

Comment: @Budda: [General Refence](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/): [SteelSeries Zboard](http://steelseries.com/products/games/starcraft-ii/steelseries-zboard-limited-edition-starcraft-ii): It can be fully customized through the use of the included SteelSeries Z Engine software which enables macros to be dragged and dropped onto specific keys by use of the program. ~ It sounds to me that these are pre-built macros that are allowed and thus those don't allow you to play better than someone without a keyboard.

Comment: Are there any pre-build macros in StarCraft 2? Really?

Comment: @Budda: In StarCraft 2? No.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. When user presses a key it goes to -> keyboard controller -> driver -> win (API message) -> game.

I don't know what realization did steelseries used but if macros reside on driver or even controller side then even OS cannot tell if it's user press or not

Actually many keyboard configurators / macros software work with win messages and that's how game know what happens.

**edit**

as you can see from description SteelSeries puts simple key remapping as 'macro'. It was really helpful before user able to edit keyboard layout in-game.
Anyway it doesn't mean that other devices cannot do real macro.

Comment: I'm not so sure... I would say that the driver sends the proper sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use your best judgment. If you think it may be cheating it probably is.

SC2 now provides the ability to remap keys in-game so under most circumstances you shouldn't need a 3rd party software or fancy keyboards to accomplish what you need.

A macro such as build a drone -> s,d would probably not get you banned.

However, a macro such as select queens, inject all hatches, sleep for 26 seconds and repeat would.

Anytime you introduce a time delay or looping into a macro, you are boting and may get banned.

Comment: I have a talk with Blizzard support and they tell that hard key remapping (one to one) is fine. But anything over this _probably_ may be threated as ban reason.