# What keyboard macros are useful?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have to wonder how much keyboard macros can really help in sc2. Are there really key sequences which can improve mechanics? I am skeptical but I've never tried it. I guess I can boil it down to this principle:

If the sequence is simple enough to be macro'd, isn't it extremely easy to just do it manually? A sequence of keystrokes becomes second nature *very* quickly.

There's no way a macro could be useful for microing or unit control. I think it could only be useful for macro mechanics, but stuff like building drones doesn't seem worth macro'ing. Queen injections seem impossible to macro because it requires mouse involvement. Maybe something like a macro which does:

<kbd>CTRL+9</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>R button click</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>

Assuming you always hotkey a worker to <kbd>1</kbd>, then this macro would bring your worker to where your cursor is without losing your current unit selection. Maybe could be a way for terran to bring workers out to repair on the battlefield? But again, this seems kinda ridiculous.

So, what macros are genuinely useful?

[The subject of whether they are against the terms of service is a different issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/keyboard-with-macros-support-from-blizzard).

Comment: Queen-injection can be macroed - backspace places the next base at the center of the screen

Comment: but it doesn't click the hatchery for you....

Comment: Yes, but mouse movement/clicking is easy to macro.  You can't tell AutoHotkey to "right-click on the hatchery" - but you *can* easily tell it to "right-click on the middle of the screen".

Comment: I don't think you'll find many macros that are fully beneficial since so much of the game relies on clicking. You might be able to macro up a button that does Ctrl+9 to set a hot key, but that's it as far as rapid succession key-presses.

Comment: @BLue If you're getting a macro to click on a certain area of a screen, then you are definitely entering the area of cheating and having something "play the game for you".

Comment: @Sorean: As I understand it, using macros in any form, keyboard or mouse, is considered cheating and can get you banned.  The link in the question supports that.  I never claimed that it wasn't cheating - just that it's not "impossible to do" as stated in the question.

Comment: Fair enough, but within the realm of keyboard macros, they can't move the mouse for you. Unless you have a really nice keyboard. And even then, that will take some programming.

Comment: I've said this [before](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/keyboard-with-macros-support-from-blizzard/17632#17632) and I'll say it again: All Keyboard Macros are prohibited in Starcraft 2.

Comment: Another way to ask what I mean here is, "Macro keyboards are banned. But does that actually make gameplay any harder for anyone?" or maybe the fact that keyboard macros don't actually help at all is why Blizzard doesn't seem to care that much about enforcing the ban. Anyway yea this is more of a forum thread and less of a SE question; voted to close as my wimpy plea to not discuss the allowance of macros will be ignored (looking @ you @tzenes :D).

Comment: @tenfour I got a parser exception for your comment, can you rephrase?

Comment: Hehe at the end of my question, I link to the question you link to, and say that "whether this it's prohibited or not is irrelevant to this question, and already discussed elsewhere". Then I should have predicted people would ignore that, and start talking about whether it's prohibited or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cheating in multiplayer, which the community has deemed off-topic: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games

Answer (score 2):

- stutter step
- larva inject
- infested terran/transfuse/drop + click, then bind to mousewheel
- overlord drops
- drop lift micro
- larva inject reminder

Anything is possible. Hard to program? Maybe, depends on your skills, but not impossible.